# Error while trying to print out arraylist from folder

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm having some problems with these lines on Android Studio.
Basically I'm trying to get an ArrayList from a folder "abc" and then print it in the layout page "activity_max"... Android tells me that there's an error on this line:

`wordView.setText(max.get(index));` //ERROR: `cannot resolve method setText(java.io.file)`

here's the whole code, can you help me finding the problem please? Actually I'm on my first steps learning Android and Java... thank you for your patience......

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_max);

    File f = new File("file:///app/assets/abc");
    ArrayList<File> max = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(f.listFiles()));

    LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_max);

    for (int index = 0; index < max.size(); index ++)

    {
        TextView wordView = new TextView(this);
        wordView.setText(max.get(index)); //ERROR: cannot resolve method setText(java.io.file)
        rootView.addView(wordView);

    }
}
```

Comment: `trying to print out arraylist from folder`. Terrible description. You want to print file and folder names of a directory. But your directory path does not exist and you use the File class wrong. And you cannot use the File class for files in assets.

Comment: `f.listFiles()` will return `null` so trying to make an array out of it will crash your application. Do not put so many statement in one code line as if somenthing goes wrong (as it does now) you will not know where. Do statements one by one and always check return values before further use.

Comment: `Android tells me that there's an error on this line: `. No. Not Android. But Android Studio. It will only be Android if you have a app and it runs on an Android device. You have no app yet as your code does not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to feed TextView with File object. Depends on what you need to do you can try printing file names like this:

```
wordView.setText(max.get(index).getName());
```

Comment: Thank you for being so fast, it gives me no more errors on the code but once I click on the button in the app that should show me the arrayList, the app crashes and this message shows up "unfortunately your app has stopped", maybe some problems with the folder path?

Comment: What is the exception you are getting? Check the logcat.

Comment: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.maxhelperv0/com.example.android.maxhelperv0.MaxActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null"

does it mean the folder is empty? (the folder has 303 elements actually)

Comment: check if file.exists() if it's a false, then your path has probably some typo in it or you may not have permissions for the folder.

Comment: ok thank you for your patience, I'm going to figure it out by myself but your first answer actually solved the problem, this error I'm getting now is another thing so thank you again